# Enigmarch Day 3: Shadow

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

<sub>This puzzle was created as part of [Enigmarch](https://enigmarch.com/), a daily puzzle construction challenge.</sub>

---

[image]

A spreadsheet of the puzzle is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1US2K6AiCoreg7l_pwba38HpX0ik99TpAmG_8fPk2oAY/edit#gid=1012552837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions to the grids:

> [image]

Now to follow some instructions:

> From grid 1, 6A we know we have to **STACK** the grids on top of each other, and from grid 2, 7A that this will form a 5x5 **CUBE**.
>
> From clues in the remaining grids, we need to look at the shadows formed when looking from the **TOP**, **LEFT** and **FRONT** in order to spell out the answer

This gives us:

> [image]
>
> Giving the final answer **SKY**!

Comment: It seems like SKY is the answer, and you've misinterpreted which part is which. I believe that the grids are supposed to be sitting flat on the ground and stacked vertically, rather than upright slices.

Comment: Also, minor typo in your screenshot of Grid 3 clue list: AU vs AG :)

Comment: @Deusovi ahh that makes much more sense with the use of the word 'stack', thanks!

Comment: @Stiv its been a while since I had a chemistry class :P